# Implement a function that will iterate over an n-sized container of shapes and sum their area using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, math

I'm currently trying to solve a problem as follows:

> Implement an object hierarchy which contains at least classes for a rectangle, a triangle and a circle. Implement a function float SumArea() that will iterate over an n-sized container of these shapes and sum their area. Also implement functions void AddTriangle(float b, float h), void AddSquare(float size), void AddCircle(float radius).

- Note 1: You need only write a single function for each class (plus the constructor).
- Note 2: The total sum of areas is required, regardless if the shapes overlap.
- Note 3: Try to make the iteration code as optimal as possible.

So far I've managed to write classes for the shapes as well as a method for each to calculate their area (the question is a bit confusing as it says rectangle but then has a function called addsquare in the answer class). I've also added the areas together in sum area but am a bit lost as to how I can calculate the area even if the shapes overlap in the container?

Here is what I have so far:

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
    area() {
        return this.size * this.size;
    }
}

class Triangle {
    constructor(base, height) {
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }
    area() {
        return this.base * this.height / 2;
    }
}

class Circle {
    constructor(radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    area() {
        return Math.PI * this.radius ** 2;
    }
}

class Answer {
    addTriangle(b, h) {
        const triangle = new Triangle(b, h);
        return triangle.area();
    }
    
    addSquare(size) {
        const rectangle = new Rectangle(size);
        return rectangle.area();
    }
    
    addCircle(radius) {
        const circle = new Circle(radius);
        return circle.area();
    }
    
    sumArea() {
        return Answer.addTriangle + Answer.addSquare + Answer.addCircle;
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"but am a bit lost as to how I can calculate the area even if the shapes overlap in the container"_ - Note 2 tells you to ignore this. Just add up the individual areas.

Comment: "container" means a collection (datastructure) to store shapes. `sumArea` shall iterate one of those and return the sum of areas. Your implementation isn't doing that.

Comment: To expand on that  ^ Your `Answer` class should have an `container: []` property. Your `add<Shape>` functions should push a new shape into that array. Then `sumArea` should iterate over the `container` and add up all areas (`reduce` is what you want there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation isn't working with a container, as the assignment is telling you to do. It requires you to store a list of shapes that you iterate over when you call the `sumArea` method

He's a snippet to help you in the right direction:

```js
class Rectangle {
    constructor(size) { this.size = size; }
    area() { return this.size * this.size; }
}

class Triangle {
    constructor(base, height) { this.base = base; this.height = height; }
    area() { return this.base * this.height / 2; }
}

class Circle {
    constructor(radius) { this.radius = radius; }
    area() { return Math.PI * this.radius ** 2; }
}

class Answer {
    container = [];

    addTriangle(b, h) {
        this.container.push(new Triangle(b, h));
    }

    // Implement `addSquare` and `addCircle`
    
    sumArea() {
        // Iterate over `this.container` here, to add together all shapes'
        // areas in the container. Look into using `reduce` for that.
    }
}

const answer = new Answer();

answer.addTriangle(3, 5);
answer.addTriangle(4, 1);
// answer.addSquare(2, 4);
// answer.addCircle(6);

console.log(answer.sumArea());
```